# Минимальное значение в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Можно ли для целочисленного поля в базе задать минимальное значение? Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при понижении значения оно не могло опуститься ниже нуля.

Comment: думаю, что надо триггер делать. что впрочем совсем не сложно

Comment: триггер тут не нужен, нужно просто сделать правильное поле

Answer (score 4):

тип данных   int unsigned / bigint unsigned / и т.д.

При попытке записать число меньше нуля, будет бросать ошибку, ловишь ее или игнорируешь. Никакие триггеры тут не нужны. Т.е. можешь, конечно, сделать триггер, но ты *замечательно* (в том смысле, что ты сможешь *заметить* глазёнками время выполнения на большом апдейте/инсерте) просядешь по производительности.

Триггер *мог бы быть* нужен, если есть определенное минимальное значение, допустим, 10. Но на **самом деле** и здесь он не нужен, поскольку вычитать 10 из добавляемого значения надо еще до записи в базу, на уровне приложения.

Минимальное  допустимое значение может измениться (например, какой-нибудь НДС), и тебе в итоге придется следить и за кодом и за триггером.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-overview.html

```
mysql> create table uns (ab int unsigned);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)

mysql> insert into uns values(2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into uns values(-1);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'ab' at row 1
mysql> update uns set ab = -1;
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'ab' at row 1
mysql> update uns set ab = ab-1000;
ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`db`.`uns`.`ab` - 1000)'
```

т.е. на самом деле `unsigned` нужен для дополнительных гарантий по консистентности данных в базе и для ловли ошибок в коде. Ну и для тех случаев, когда вы знаете, что у вас могут быть ооочень большие, например ID. Поскольку unisgned тип, условно говоря, даст в два раза больше  положительных значений, чем signed тип.  Поэтому игнорировать не советую.